# React input text default value and onblur function make input text read only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

guys, I am working on react js

I have created an input text and on blur of that input button I am calling a method and updating the state variable

but seem like if I use on blur instead of onChange then input text become read only field

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="0.13.3" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react-jsx@*" data-semver="0.13.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/jsx">

      var App = React.createClass({
          getInitialState: function () {
              return {value: 'Hello!'};
          },

          changeTo: function (e) {
              this.setState({value: e.target.value});
          },

          render: function () {
              return (
                  <div>{this.state.value}
                      <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.value || ''} 
                         value={this.state.value} onBlur={(e) => this.changeTo(e)} />
                  </div>
              );
          }
      });

      React.render(
          <App />,
          document.getElementById('app')
      );
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you use only onBlur, then input become uncontrolled. You should use onChange to reflect(for controlled input) the change. What actually the question is?

Comment: I don't want to use onchange instead can't i just use the onblur ? if so then what will be solution to use onblur

Comment: for reflecting change, use onChange... for any other special case for blur(like updating other things), use onBlur.

Comment: A typical reason to use `onBlur`/onfocusout instead of `onChange` is that the input box state is interpreted and has invalid (or valid but problematic) states. Imagine if the textbox represents time-of-day, so the internal state is a `Date`. When the user types `9:15` this is a sequence of characters - `9`, `:`, etc. If `9` by itself is interpreted as `9:00am` we do not want the input box to change instantly to `9:00am`. Handling focusout/onblur is a well-known classic way to defer reinterpretation of a textbox, but React bizarrely prevents it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add onChange listener otherwise it will not work.

Reason: When you specify value={this.state.value} it means you are binding input text value to the variable value and react takes over the control for updating value in input box. By adding onChange listener, you tell react to  call a component function to update value which basically updates the state of the component forcing it to call render function and updating the value in input text.

```
      changeTo: function (e) {
          this.setState({value: e.target.value});
      },

      updateValue: function (e) {
          this.setState({value: e.target.value});
      },

      render: function () {
          return (
              <div>{this.state.value}
                  <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.value || ''} value={this.state.value} 
onBlur={(e) => this.changeTo(e)} onChange={(e) => this.updateValue(e}/>
              </div>
          );
      }
```

Comment: the React specs don't allow the use of both 'value' and 'defaultValue' at the same time since the former makes the element controlled while the latter makes it uncontrolled